# Dollar sign in the middle of JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to think I know JavaScript okay, but I've recently seen something interesting in one of the codebases I had access to (for a very limited time). I saw a JavaScript object with a name that looked similar to this:

`Variable$Name$Example$Here = ...`

In fact, I'm not even sure if that's a variable per-se, or a different type of JavaScript object (i.e. a primitive or not). Now I know that $ is usually used to denote an instance of a jQuery, but I haven't seen it in the middle of the object name.

Did they simply name it that way? Is there simply somewhere e.g.

`var Variable$Name$Example$Here = true;`

... or am I completely missing something here?

Comment: `$` is a valid variable name character just as any letter is. Looks like the developer is using something other than CamelCase or underscores to make it readable.

Comment: ...as well as underscore.

Comment: I've never seen the `$` used in the middle of variables, but some developers like to prepend it to variable names to represent that it holds a jQuery reference.  (i.e. `var $divs = $('div');`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valid Characters for JavaScript Variable Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

Comment: You can use many things in variable names `var π = Math.PI, r = 4;` then `2 * π * r === 25.132741228718345`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is simply the name of the variable. `$` is a valid character for a variable name.